# How to manually inject Eureka Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I try to manually inject Eureka Server in a Spring Boot project to mimic the effects of @EnableEurekaServer. I tried:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(
   value = "sd.mode",
   havingValue = "Server")
public EurekaServerAutoConfiguration startServer() {
        return new EurekaServerAutoConfiguration();
}
```

and

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "sd.mode",
        havingValue = "Server")
public class SDServer {
}
```

None worked as expected. Is there a proper way to do this?

---

Edit: to clarify the goal of this:

I want to enhance a Spring Boot application with service discovery abilities. The first step is to make the jar configurable, depending on its role. This works with a lot of components, just Eureka gives me trouble. The goal is:

(in application.properties)

```
sd.mode=server //Application loads Eureka Server
sd.mode=client //Application runs as Eureka Client
sd.mode=off //Application does not use Eureka
```

As an example for a working component:

```
@Configuration
public class OutputConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "output",
            havingValue = "ConsoleLogger",
            matchIfMissing = false)
    public Output<String, String> createConsoleLogger() {
        return new ConsoleLogger();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "output",
            havingValue = "TCPSocketWriter",
            matchIfMissing = false)
    public Output<String, String> createTCPSocketWriter() {
        return new TCPSocketWriter();
    }

}
```

With this, I can access `Output` and use the Instance I declared in application properties. I want to do something similar with Eureka.

---

Edit2: my try on M. Deinums solution (if I understood it correctly), did not show any difference.

```
public class SDServer {
    @Bean
    public SDServerConfig createSDServerConfig(){
        return new SDServerConfig();
    }
    @Configuration
    @EnableEurekaServer
    class SDServerConfig{

    }
}
```

run by

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceDiscovery {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "sd.mode",
            havingValue = "Server",
            matchIfMissing = false)
    public SDServer startServer() {
        return new SDServer();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "sd.mode",
            havingValue = "Client",
            matchIfMissing = false)
    public SDClient enableClient() {
        return new SDClient();
    }
}
```

Btw, SDClient with

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SDClient {
}
```

works as expected.

---

After correctly applying M. Deinums solution, this finally works!

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "sd.mode",
        havingValue = "Server",
        matchIfMissing = false)
public class SDServer {

    @Configuration
    @EnableEurekaServer
    static class SDServerConfig {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Looks like conditionally enabling the eureka service. Just create a nested `@Configuration` with `@EnableEurekaServer` which will only be loaded based on the condition.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. I try to do what you describe with the second approach, is the execution wrong?

Comment: It needs to be on a nested configuration class. The condition goes on the `SDServer` which should have nested conditional `@Configuration` annotation class which also has the `@EnableEurekaServer`. This prevents the `@EnableEurekaServer` from being loaded and thus processed. Your current solution doesn't.

Comment: The current solution does not load `@EnableEurekaServer` at all.

Comment: Have you actually **read** and **tried** the solution with a nested `@Configuration` class. Regular beans and configuratoin classes are different!

Comment: See the last edit.

Comment: No you haven't understood it properly which is why it doesn't work. I thought that my comment was pretty clear? create an `@Configuration` class with the `@ConditionalOnProperty` inside that `@Configuiration` class create an inner `@Configuration` class that has the `@EnableEurekaServer` annotation. I nowhere stated you should create an `@Bean` method.

Comment: Ok, after reading your answer again, I really did not apply your solution correctly. This works, thank you very much! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the configuration or bean annotation? The general way is to do it in the main class like the following code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to be able to load the Eureka Server via configuration. In this case, the bean is launched on a property in the application.properties. I would be happy with another way which would achieve the same.

Comment: check my other answer. I have detailed out the solution

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use eureka server and client. In the eureka server project add the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` dependency and use the following annotations in the main class.

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

In the yml file
server:
port: 8761

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

And for the other services that you want to register in the server, you must also use the same dependency. However, you must use the following lines on the config file

```
spring.application.name=app-name
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Comment: This just runs a eureka server or client. Eureka Server runs just with the annotation and no further configuration, so just skipping the configuration does not provide an on/off switch. I will clarify the goals in the first post.